# Why the table data is no being appending properly

Tags: jquery

I am displaying table dynamically with the json response i got .

The issue i am facing is that , the table is being shown with data as well as this below

```
Symbol  Close   Change(Rs)  Change(%)   AS ON
Symbol  Close   Change(Rs)  Change(%)   AS ON
Symbol  Close   Change(Rs)  Change(%)   AS ON
Symbol  Close   Change(Rs)  Change(%)   AS ON
```

This si my code

```
<section class="widget">
   <div>
      <table id="1d" class="losstable tablesorter">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Symbol</th>
               <th>Close</th>
               <th>Change(Rs)</th>
               <th>Change(%)</th>
               <th>AS ON</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
      <table id="1w" class="losstable tablesorter">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Symbol</th>
               <th>Close</th>
               <th>Change(Rs)</th>
               <th>Change(%)</th>
               <th>AS ON</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
      <table id="2w" class="losstable tablesorter">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Symbol</th>
               <th>Close</th>
               <th>Change(Rs)</th>
               <th>Change(%)</th>
               <th>AS ON</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
      <table id="3w" class="losstable tablesorter">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Symbol</th>
               <th>Close</th>
               <th>Change(Rs)</th>
               <th>Change(%)</th>
               <th>AS ON</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
      <table id="1m" class="losstable tablesorter">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Symbol</th>
               <th>Close</th>
               <th>Change(Rs)</th>
               <th>Change(%)</th>
               <th>AS ON</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</section>
```

This is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/7607/

Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at your jsfiddle, you have different tables with id's but you select only the first table with id `#1d` and append data to the tbody of that first table. The other tables headers are still being printed.

in you jsfiddle you have `var tableid = "#1d";` but after that nothing happens with that tableid except your call to insert the html. Looks like your code is just not complete/finished.

Comment: thanks ,but my code is completed , just i want to append the data to the table .

Comment: i have tried this way  $('.losstable table').not(tableid ).hide();

Comment: i somehow reslolved the issue , thank you very much Christophe and Ashsish.

Comment: Sorry forgot to check back. You could hide them by default using css and only display the table once you append data to it just by adding `.show()`. so for example `.html(html).show();`

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableclass = ".tablesorter";
var html = "";

for (var s = 0; s < jsonresp.length; s++) 
{
    var symbol = jsonresp[s].symbol,
    close = jsonresp[s].todays_close,
    prev_close = jsonresp[s].prev_close,
    as_on = "YDA";
    d = parseFloat(close) - parseFloat(prev_close), d = d.toFixed(2);
    var l = (close - prev_close) / close * 100;
    l = l.toFixed(2), html += "<tr><td>" + symbol + "</td><td>" + close + '</td><td class="redclass">' + d + '</td><td  class="redclass">' + l + '</td><td class="">' + prev_close + "(" + as_on + ")</td></tr>";
}
$(".widget > div > table > tbody").html(html);
</script>
```

Comment: i have got many tables using tablesorter as its class so cannot use this cod e.

Comment: there are four table is fix  like 1d, 1w, etc.

Comment: Use This Code :  $(".widget > div > table > tbody").html(html);